wiremock in java offset 1 hour
help please.
trying using in wiremock dynamic data
Wiremock editing in intellij idea
"expiresAt": "{{now offset='1 hour' timezone='Australia/Sydney' format='unix'}}",
but got error when ask this url
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.helpers.DateOffset.Unit.HOUR

The correct form is 1 hours, even if singular.
